# Modify attributes and field calculator in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, attribute-table

I have approximately 200 point shapefiles that have been created from ASCII grid files.

Each one has a Grid_code heading in the attribute table, I need to add in a new heading called height or depth which is a double of length 16, precision 2 that equals the grid code (basically the grid_code but to 2 decimal places). Is there a way to do this in ModelBuilder or another way that saves me from doing them all manually?

Also would be good to delete the grid_code afterwards but this is not essential.

Comment: Unless you have prior experience with Model Builder, it would probably easier to just batch `Add Field` and `Calculate Field`. You can do this by right clicking the tool name in toolbox.